# Projection of Maximum Likelihood

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, maximum-likelihood

Let $P_1,P_2$ be probability measures on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathfrak{G})$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $Y$ be data generated from either $P_i;i=1,2$.
Then the likelihoods satisfy
\begin{equation}
L(P_1|Y)>L(P_2|Y),
\label{eq_1}
\end{equation}
if and only if $Y$ was generated from $P_1$ and not from $P_2$ right?

My question is then, if $\mathfrak{F}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathfrak{G}$, then does
$$
L(P_1(-|\mathfrak{F})|Y)>L(P_2(-|\mathfrak{F})|Y),
$$
hold if and only if the first equation holds?  Here $P_i(-|\mathfrak{F})$ is the conditional measure $P_i$ given the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{F}$ of $\mathfrak{G}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Your premise is false:** Consider the simple example $Y \sim \text{Bern}(p_i)$ with parameters $p_1 < p_2$ under the two models.  Under either model the likelihood (with respect to counting measure) is:

$$L_y(p_i) = (1-p_i)^{1-y} p_i^y.$$

Now, suppose that you generate from the Model 1 and get $y = 1$ (which occurs with probability $p_1$).  Then you have $L_y(p_1) = p_1 < p_2 = L_y(p_2)$.  So your initial claim about the likelihood inequality is false.  (Perhaps what you meant to do was to give an inequality of the *expected* likelihoods, when $Y$ has a particular distribution under the models?)